# How to replace string that's only before a symbol

Tags: c#

Doing practice with a note app, I have a text file that contain notes by line numbering like this:

> 1) First note
>
> 2) Second note
>
> n) n note

Anticipating that a user may remove a note from the list, I want to avoid having these notes un-organized, so the lines numbers would be re-organized automatically.

```
int NumérotationFromTheUserTextFile, NumérotationInOrder = 1;
string[] Strings = File.ReadAllLines(logPath);
for(int i=0; i<Strings.Length; i++)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(logPath))
    {
        string text = File.ReadLines(logPath).Skip(i).Take(1).First();
        string[] bits = text.Split(')');
        if(int.TryParse(bits[0], out int x)) 
        {
            NumérotationFromTheUserTextFile = x;
            if (NumérotationFromTheUserTextFile != NumérotationInOrder)
            {
                Strings[i] = Strings[i].Replace(NumérotationFromTheUserTextFile.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), NumérotationInOrder.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
            NumérotationInOrder++;
        }
    }
}    
File.WriteAllLines(logPath, Strings);
```

The code above does the job EXCEPT it does affect/change all other similar numbers at the same line. and I want it to stop editing at each line by this symbol ')'.

Any suggestion on how to improve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace it in `bits[0]` and join them back. `String.Split` has an overload that takes a maximum number of substrings.

Comment: It seems a lot simpler if you could just rewrite the whole file writing the correct note numbers

Comment: why not take text[0]? or text.Trim()[0] if you're worried about whitespace? Alternatively, you can do String[i].Replace(NumerotationFromTheUserTextFile + ")", NumerotationInOrder + ")")

Comment: It seems like a design flaw to store the line number with the line itself. That's something you can determine at runtime when you load the note, and you can display them in your UI without writing them to the file. Since it's obvious that the user has access to modify the file outside of your application, the fewer "rules" you have about the contents of each line the better.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. KMoussa's answer did what I just needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, it seems like a design flaw to store the line number with the line itself. That's something you can determine at runtime when you load the note, and you can display them in your UI without writing them to the file. Since it's obvious that the user has access to modify the file outside of your application, the fewer "rules" you have about the contents of each line the better.

However, if you need to store `'#)` at the start of each line, then we need to validate a couple of things:

1. If the line does not contain a `')'` character, add `#)` to the beginning of the line
2. If the line doesn't start with numeric text, add `#)` to the beginning of the line
3. If the number before the `')'` character is not correct, modify it.

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static void ReNumberLines(string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(nameof(filePath));

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var num = i + 1;
        var parts = lines[i].Split(new[] {')'}, 2);  // Split on the first ')'

        // If there was no ')' character, add a line number to this line
        if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            lines[i] = $"{num}) {parts[0].Trim()}";
            continue;
        }

        // Try to determine if we need to modify the beginning of the line.
        // If it starts with non-numeric characters, add '#)'
        // Otherwise if the number doesn't match, replace it with the correct #
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out number))
        {
            // There was a number before the ')', so if it matches we can continue
            if (number == num) continue;

            // Otherwise replace it with the correct number
            lines[i] = $"{num}) {parts[1].Trim()}";
        }
        else
        {
            // The characters before the ')' are not numeric, so we have to assume that
            // user content is here and prefix this line with the correct number and ')'
            lines[i] = $"{num}) {parts[0]}){parts[1]}";
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this one `String[i].Replace(NumerotationFromTheUserTextFile + ")", NumerotationInOrder + ")") ` did the trick without changing all the code.